# XQuery: Item expected, sequence found error

Tags: xml, xquery

XML:

```
<data>
    <providers>
        <provider num="v1">
            <name>Smith</name>
            <state>20</state>
            <city>London</city>
        </provider>
        <provider num="v2">
            <name>Jones</name>
            <state>10</state>
            <city>Paris</city>
        </provider>
        <provider num="v3">
            <name>Adams</name>
            <state>30</state>
            <city>Athens</city>
        </provider>
    </providers>
 </data>
```

XQuery:

```
let $p := doc("providers.xml")/data/providers/provider
where $p/state > 15
return <cities>{concat($p/city/text(), ' , ')}</cities>
```

I want the output to be the name of the cities, one after the other separated by comma, but I get the error: item expected, sequence found.

Comment: Use `string-join` function instead of `concat`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is complaining about the [`concat()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-concat) function where the first parameter is a sequence of strings. It expects each item you want to concatenate to be specified as separate parameters to that function (it doesn't spread the sequence to params).

You should use [`string-join()`](https://www.w3.org/TR/2005/CR-xpath-functions-20051103/#func-string-join) instead, to produce a comma separated string with each of the cities:

```
<cities>{string-join($p/city/text(), ' , ')}</cities>
```

Comment: And as a simplification of the XPath, it suffices to use `$p/city`, not need for the `$p/city/text()`.

Comment: Interestingly, OPs `where` clause is ineffective (at least in base-x and .net xquery fiddle), that is - all 3 cities are returned. It does work if, instead, you add a predicate at the end of `$p` like so: `[state>15]`. Any idea why?

Comment: @JackFleeting, normally you would use `for .. where`, I would need to look up what meaning or non-meaning `let .. where` has.

Comment: because `$p` contains the sequence of provider elements, and there is a `city` that is greater than 15. If the intent is to filter, it should be a `for` `where` so that the where clause is filtering each item, then generate the output from the filtered set.

Comment: I see! So `where` is satisfied if any item in the sequence meets the condition, while the predicate pre-filters the sequence, as it were..

Comment: Not quite. The difference is that in one case you're comparing `$p/state` with 15, and `$p/state` is a sequence of values; in the other case you're comparig the context item with 15, and the context item is a single value.

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the comments under the previous answer the query can (and potentially should be) rewritten in one of the below options. Which works for you depends on your XQuery processor and personal preference.

FLWOR

```
let $cities :=
  for $prov in doc("providers.xml")/data/providers/provider
  where $prov/state > 15
  return $prov/city
return <cities>{string-join($cities, ' , '}</cities>
```

With a predicate

```
let $cities := doc("providers.xml")/data/providers/provider[state>15]/city
return <cities>{ string-join($cities, ' , ') }</cities>
```

Without let or return

```
<cities>{
  string-join(
    doc("providers.xml")
      /data/providers/provider[state>15]/city, ' , ')
}</cities>
```

If arrow expressions are supported:

```
<cities>{
    doc("providers.xml")
      /data/providers/provider[state>15]/city
    => string-join(' , ')
}</cities>
```